# Prove using induction that ${p - 1 \choose n} \equiv (-1)^n \bmod p$ for $0 \leq n \leq p - 1$ where $p > 2$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Can someone see if this method is correct because I have doubts using the theory of induction?

> Let $p > 2$ be a prime number. Prove that
> \begin{align*} \binom{p-1}{n} \equiv (-1)^n \, (\mathrm{mod} \, {p}) \;  \text{for any number }  \ 0 \leq n \leq p-1  \end{align*}

### My Attempt

\begin{align*}
\binom{p}{n} = \binom{p-1}{n} + \binom{p-1}{n-1} 
\end{align*}

Is divisible by $p$. Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\binom{p-1}{n} = - \binom{p-1}{n-1} \pmod p
\end{align*}

Hence, for the induction step,
\begin{align*}
\binom{p-1}{n-1} \equiv (-1)^{n-1} \pmod p
\end{align*}

It follows that

\begin{align*}
\binom{p-1}{n} \equiv (-1)^n \pmod p
\end{align*}

It was the first time I wrote in MathJax.
It took me a long time... but here goes with practice. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need the base case about ${p-1}\choose0$ and also need some condition for $n$ in the first equation (or else, your proof would also "show" the result for $n>p$). --- Incidentally, the restriction $p>2$ is never needed.

Comment: Be careful with the initialization of the recursion (you skipped this step). And precise that you take $1 \le n \le p-1$ before saying that $p$ divides ${p \choose n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, as you fix $p$ to be a fixed prime number, and attempt to prove for all $0\leq n\leq p-1$ that;
$$\binom{p}{n}=(-1)^n\pmod{p}.$$

In this approach, however, we need to first prove that the claim does hold for $n=0$ and $n=1$ which are the Base Cases. Once we have proved the statement for $n=0$ and $1$, we can approach the Inductive Step; to prove that if the statement is true for $n-1$ and $n$ in $\{0,1,2,\dots, p-2\},$ then it is also true for $n+1.$

Once we have done this, we can see the dominoes falling as the claim gets proven for all of the required numbers;
\begin{align*}
\text{Claim true for }n=0\text{ and }1 &\implies \text{So claim also true for }n=2\\
\text{Claim true for }n=1\text{ and }2 &\implies \text{So claim also true for }n=3\\
\text{Claim true for }n=2\text{ and }3 &\implies \text{So claim also true for }n=4\\
&\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\vdots\\
\text{Claim true for }n=p-3\text{ and }p-2 &\implies \text{So claim also true for }n=p-1.
\end{align*}

Finally, we Can see its true for all of the required values of $n.$ Hope this method works out for you.